# how to avoid geom_text from being cut off

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following chart in R created using `ggplot2`. Some of the labels I've generated using `geom_text` are cut off when I use a `vjust` argument equal to -1 (For example the July label in the first and second facet). The same thing would happen if I used a `vjust` argument equal to +1 for all of the labels. Is there a way to optimise the location of by labels without having to specify each `vjust` manually in a vector?

The reason why I'm looking to avoid specifying each vjust manually in a vector is because I want the chart to be as flexible to any changes in the Values as possible.

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(18779, 18809, 18840, 18871, 
18901, 18932, 18779, 18809, 18840, 18871, 18901, 18932, 18779, 
18809, 18840, 18871, 18901, 18932), class = "Date"), Key = c("Category 1", 
"Category 1", "Category 1", "Category 1", "Category 1", "Category 1", 
"Category 2", "Category 2", "Category 2", "Category 2", "Category 2", 
"Category 2", "Category 3", "Category 3", "Category 3", "Category 3", 
"Category 3", "Category 3"), Value = c(2.8, 3, 2, 2.7, 2.7, 2.8, 
1, 2, -1.2, 0.3, 0.6, 0.8, 4, 3.7, 4.4, 4.4, 4.2, 4.2)), row.names = c(NA, 
-18L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

ggplot(data, aes(Date, Value, col = Key)) +
      geom_line(size = 2)  +
      facet_wrap(~Key, scales = 'free_y', nrow = 3) +
      guides(col='none', linetype='none') +
      geom_text(aes(label = paste0(sprintf('%0.1f', round(Value, digits = 2)), '%')), size = 5, 
                vjust = -1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(18779, 18809, 18840, 18871, 
 18901, 18932, 18779, 18809, 18840, 18871, 18901, 18932, 18779, 
 18809, 18840, 18871, 18901, 18932), class = "Date"), Key = c("Category 1", 
 "Category 1", "Category 1", "Category 1", "Category 1", "Category 1", 
 "Category 2", "Category 2", "Category 2", "Category 2", "Category 2", 
 "Category 2", "Category 3", "Category 3", "Category 3", "Category 3", 
 "Category 3", "Category 3"), Value = c(2.8, 3, 2, 2.7, 2.7, 2.8, 
 1, 2, -1.2, 0.3, 0.6, 0.8, 4, 3.7, 4.4, 4.4, 4.2, 4.2)), row.names = c(NA, 
 -18L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


fvjust = function(data) data %>%
  mutate(vjust = ifelse(Value>mean(Value),2, -2))

df = data %>% group_by(Key) %>% 
  group_modify(~fvjust(.x))

df %>% ggplot(aes(Date, Value, col = Key)) +
  geom_line(size = 2)  +
  facet_wrap(~Key, scales = 'free_y', nrow = 3) +
  guides(col='none', linetype='none') +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(sprintf('%0.1f', round(Value, digits = 2)), '%')), size = 5, 
            vjust = df$vjust)
```

[image]